# Hololens2 with MRTK 2.6.1 Losing Head Pose after device Sleep

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

On Hololens2 if the device goes to sleep (or press the power button off then on) and resume my app I lose head pose tracking.

I'm using MRTK 2.6.1 with Unity 2019.4.18f and the XR SDK approach.

I'm testing using the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02?tabs=winxr

I'm using the DefaultHololens2XRSDKConfiguration profile.

Everything is generally fine, but after I put the headset down and it goes to sleep, or i press the power button off and on. Then launch my app again (it's still running in the background), then the head tracking is lost.

The wrist tap menu is still tracked fine. The app seems to be getting hand tracking fine (but is offset becaues the head pose position is stuck.

If i close the app and open again tracking is fine.

No errors show up in the Unity debug log (even with verbose MRTK logging on).

Any ideas? Or anyone else able to test this with similar setup?

I might try the Open XR approach next.
Cheers

Comment: May I know your HoloLens 2 OS version? Besides, it seems like the issue lies with the resuming operation. Could you try to suspend and resume your app by OS Shell UI? Do you see the same behavior?

Comment: I'm on 10.0.19041.1144. 
I'm just closing the app with the System Menu. If I resume without the device sleeping then everything is fine. But if the device sleeps and I come back then the camera tracking stops updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with a fix in development still, it is recommended to keep checking the Unity releases for 2019 with getting on latest LTS for now.

Comment: Thanks for checking on this. Is there a bug database with known issues? I couldn't find any info on this, but I guess it's fairly recent and awkward to search for

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no public tracking issue I can share with you here. Please keep checking the Unity release notes for XR SDK updates to 2.8 for Unity 2019 LTS. Over the next release or two is the understanding.

Comment: Unity 2019.4.27 with XR SDK 2.8 fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in Windows XR SDK 2.8 which requires Unity 2019.4.25 or later.